# Check array for multiple keys

Tags: php

Is it possible to check in one go if multiple keys exists in an array, instead of using the `array_key_exists` function multiple times? Or, can this be achieved another way?

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);

if(array_key_exists('first','second' $search_array))//Do something like this. 
{
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this function very good to use if you need to verify many variables:

**In http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
manhon824 at gmail dot com First note**

```
<?php
function array_key_exists_r($keys, $search_r) {
    $keys_r = split('\|',$keys);
    foreach($keys_r as $key)
    if(!array_key_exists($key,$search_r))
    return false;
    return true;
}
?>

e.g.

<?php
if(array_key_exists_r('login|user|passwd',$_GET)) {
// login
} else {
// other
}
?>
```

In http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

manhon824 at gmail dot com First note

Changed your code like above example

Comment: `split` is a deprecated function. Use `explode`.

Answer (score 2):

Not an out of the box function, The solution by Samitha Hewawasam has if fully commented.

```
if(array_key_exists_r('first|second',$search_array)) {
    // searching for items in array
} else {
    // other
}
```

This should help you out. It will search for your items seperated by pipes (|)
I pull this from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: You should probably include the example function `array_key_exists_r` from the comment on php.net, otherwise it seems like this is a default solution.

Comment: Renaming that function to `areset` to use as replacement  for `isset` makes it much more comformable to type repeatedly. And yes, I know  `isset` returns `false` when the value of the key is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function keysInArray ($array, $keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key)
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array))
            return false; // failure, if any key doesn't exist
    return true; // else true; it hasn't failed yet
}
```

And call it with:

```
if (keysInArray($searchArray, array("key1", "key2", /*...*/))) { /* ... */ }
```

And yes, you have to use multiple checks (e.g. in a loop); there doesn't exist an all-in-one function.